# electron-vue ~ Cannot update vuex state with RxJS subscribe

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, electron-vue

I have two functions in my **mutations** and two **state**

```html
const state = {
  files: [],
  uploadProgress: 0
}

const mutations = {

  SET_UPLOAD_IMAGE: (state, files) => {
    state.files = files
  },

  UPLOAD_IMAGE: (state) => {
    StandbyService.uploadImage(state.files).subscribe(progress => {
      state.uploadProgress += progress
      console.log(`Upload Progress ${progress}%`)
    })
  }

}
```

**SET_UPLOAD_IMAGE** is used to set the **files** state and **UPLOAD_IMAGE** is used to trigger uploading the image to the server. The upload process run and return the upload progress. My `uploadImage()` return an Observable and I want to update the **uploadProgress** state whenever the progress is received, but I can't do such that. It keep on giving error in the console as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I don't know what to do with this error. I already spent more than 4 hours with this.
I really appreciate for helps and suggestions. Thank you very much.

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: @MazinoSUkah No It's not working till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use actions for all async task. That's what documentations says

> Actions are similar to mutations, the differences being that:
>
> 1. Instead of mutating the state, actions commit mutations.
> 2. Actions cancontain arbitrary asynchronous operations.

Also it's important that mutations are not async, as mentioned in the docs.

> One important rule to remember is that mutation handler functions must
>   be synchronous.

So well you can write an action and commit your progress as needed

```
const state = {
  files: [],
  uploadProgress: 0
}
const action:{
  uploadImage({commit,state}, payload){
   StandbyService.uploadImage(state.files).subscribe(progress => {
      commit('updateProgress', progress)
      console.log(`Upload Progress ${progress}%`)
    })
  })
  }
}
const mutations = {

  SET_UPLOAD_IMAGE: (state, files) => {
    state.files = files
  },

  UPLOAD_IMAGE: (state) => {
    //you don't need it anymore
  },

  UPDATE_PROGRESS: (state, progress){
    state.uploadProgress += progress
  },

}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to vue, updating the state without mutation is an antipattern.

> The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing a mutation

That is why you are getting this warning.

Try writing a mutation, instead of writing `state.uploadProgress += progress` write a mutation similar to `SET_UPLOAD_IMAGE`.

That's all it should work.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ahh I see! But how can I commit a mutation inside a mutation function? If possible, Can you give me some sample? Thank you!

Comment: As I checked with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487627/can-i-call-commit-from-one-of-mutations-in-vuex-store/42839744](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487627/can-i-call-commit-from-one-of-mutations-in-vuex-store/42839744) they mentioned that `commit` is `undefined`

Comment: you can do a work around, by dispatching one action and inside that action you commit both of your mutations.